# Nuxt.js code gives NaN error while calculating data from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I have code for calculating orders from given arrays that works in nuxt envoriment. I've created 3 functions each of them calculates a number from arrays, if i console.log first function it gives me a true result but other functions that are connected to it calculates similarly but when i put them to console.log they give Nan error.(Arrays are coming in string format)

I have tried parseFloat() to every possible place but again Not a Number error comes at console

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

 // Import and Set Nuxt.js options
    const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
    config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

    let loopInterval = null

    async function start() {
      // Init Nuxt.js
      const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

      const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

      // Build only in dev mode
      if (config.dev) {
        const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
        await builder.build()
      } else {
        await nuxt.ready()
      }

      // Add this part
      app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
        codeLoop()
        res.send('My code loop started.')
      })

      app.get('/stop', (req, res) => {
        clearInterval(loopInterval)
        loopInterval = null
        res.send('My code loop stopped')
      })

      // Give nuxt middleware to express
      app.use(nuxt.render)

      // Listen the server
      app.listen(port, host)
      consola.ready({
        message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
        badge: true
      })
    }
    start()
    let UsdtTrySell = [["5.45","400"],["5.44","400"],["5.43","400"]];
    let BtcUsdtSell =  [["3900","1"],["3905","1"],["3910","1"]];
    let btcTryBuy = [["21000","1"],["20950","1"],["20900","1"]];
    let UsdtOrder = 1000;

    function runMyCode() {
      consola.log('hello')
    }  
    function codeLoop() {
      runMyCode()
      loopInterval = setInterval(async () => {              
        function SellUsdtTryAtBtrk() {
          let inputOrder1 = UsdtOrder
          let sum = 0
          let i = 0
          for (i = 0; i < parseFloat(UsdtTrySell.length); i++) {
            if (parseFloat(UsdtTrySell[i][1]) < inputOrder1) {
              sum += UsdtTrySell[i][0] * UsdtTrySell[i][1]
              inputOrder1 -= parseFloat(UsdtTrySell[i][1])
            } else {
              return sum + inputOrder1 * parseFloat(UsdtTrySell[i][0])
            }
          }
          return ''
        }
        function BuyBtcTryAtBtrk() {
          let inputOrder2 = SellUsdtTryAtBtrk
          let sum1 = 0
          let i = 0
          for (i = 0; i < (parseFloat(btcTryBuy.length)); i++) {
            if ( parseFloat(btcTryBuy[i][0]) *  parseFloat(btcTryBuy[i][1]) < 
parseFloat(inputOrder2)) {
              sum1 +=  parseFloat(btcTryBuy[i][1])
              inputOrder2 -=  parseFloat(btcTryBuy[i][0]) *  
parseFloat(btcTryBuy[i][1])
            } else {
              return sum1 +  parseFloat(inputOrder2) / 
parseFloat(btcTryBuy[i][0])
            }
          }
          return ''
        }
        function SellBtcUsdtAtBnnc() {
          let inputOrder3 = BuyBtcTryAtBtrk
          // const BtcUsdtSell = bnncBtcusdt.bids
          let sum = 0
          let i = 0
          for (i = 0; i < (parseFloat(BtcUsdtSell.length)); i++) {
            if (parseFloat(BtcUsdtSell[i][1]) < inputOrder3) {
              sum += BtcUsdtSell[i][0] * BtcUsdtSell[i][1]
              inputOrder3 -= parseFloat(BtcUsdtSell[i][1])
            } else {
              return sum + inputOrder3 * parseFloat(BtcUsdtSell[i][0])
            }
          }
          return ''
        }
        console.log(SellBtcUsdtAtBnnc());
      }, 2 * 1000) // Runs every 2 seconds
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `inputOrder2` and `inputOrder3` to **functions** instead of assigning them to **the result of calling the functions**.

---

Change this line:

```
let inputOrder2 = SellUsdtTryAtBtrk
```

...to this:

```
let inputOrder2 = SellUsdtTryAtBtrk();
```

---

...and change this line:

```
let inputOrder3 = BuyBtcTryAtBtrk
```

...to this:

```
let inputOrder3 = BuyBtcTryAtBtrk();
```

---

...and it should work.